# How can I make this more efficient? I am trying to calculate the distance from the origin to each point in the list

Tags: list, function, distance

I am trying to calculate distance from the point in the list below

```
#Here is my list
list = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
#here is my function
def calculateDistance(x,y):
    dist = math.sqrt((x-0)**2 + (y-0)**2)
    return dist
```

I am trying to take each point and return a value for the distance into a list. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

I find the question a little unclear; I think you want to calculate the distance from all points in the list to the origin?
To do this, you just need to iterate over the list items. The problem is that these items are tuples, so you need to select the individual members of the tuple. You do this simply using indices. If the tuple is called `point`, the first element is accessed using `point[0]` and the second using `point[1]`.
(Note that the count starts at 0, not at 1. This is something  you'll often encounter in computer programming).

```
l2 = []
for point in list:
    dist = calculateDistance(point[0],point[1])
    l2.append( dist )

print( l2 )
```

Looking at your code, you may also want to determine the distance from a specific point.
In that case, I would suggest to re-define your `calculateDistance` function to accept two points and determine the distance between them. Finding out how to do this may be a good exercise.

Comment: I see your point. My goal is to calculate the distance from the origin to each point , since 0,0 will always be (X1,Y1) I figured I would only need to include the values from the list in the parameters. Thats why i included 0 in the function. So how would I write this do that I could use any point not just the origin?

Comment: @Afronaut If you really want to learn, you'll have to try and find out for yourself. I'll give you a hint: you can start it with `def calculateDistance(p,q):` where p and q are the points. If you can't figure out how to do that, try passing numbers instead of tuples first: `calculateDistance(px,py,qx,qy)`. Good luck!